# Baker, Gill, Solovay - construction of oracle B such that P^B != NP^B

Tags: complexity-theory, p-vs-np, oracles

I have some questions about Baker, Gill, Solovay proof of the existence of an oracle such that P^B != NP^B. The proof can be found in Siam Journal of Computing, 4:432-442, 1975 [219].

- Why Isn't this construction considered a counterexample to P = NP? And if it is not, can it be strengthened into one? It seems tome that we have constructed a languge recognizable in NP time but not in P time.
- In the proof there is the sentence "If P_i^B(i) accepts 0^n, then place no string into B at this stage." How can this possibly happen?

I figured that, since B is intially empty, the oracle B(i) ALWAYS rejects. So the only reason why P_i would accept is some reason OTHER than a  question to B(i). Please correct me if I am wrong.

The proof in question is verbatim reproduced here. The original paper is here.

Comment: You previously asked your first question earlier at https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/113595/755.  It would be nice to recognize the answer you already got and identify more specifically what your specific confusion with it is.

Comment: I was given the answer that it IS NOT a counterexample. Now I am asking WHY it is not a counterexample. If you want to participate in this discussion it would be more productive if you answered the question as clearly as you can instead of critiquing how people are asking a question.

Answer (score 5):

As the [original](http://cse.ucdenver.edu/~cscialtman/complexity/Relativizations%20of%20the%20P=NP%20Question%20(Original).pdf) paper is showing a lot more, I use this [one](http://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/diagchap.pdf) at page 69-70, Theorem 3.9, as this is the proof I also know.

As you can see there, the complete statement of Baker, Gill, Solovay is:

> There exist oracles $A, B$ s.t. $P^A = NP^A$ and $P^B \neq NP^B$

The second oracle cannot be considered a counterexample for $P = NP$ because you cannot "divide" by B so to say. Constructing a oracle language $L^A$ out of a "normal" language $L$ is not that easy. The languages $P^B$ and $NP^B$ behave completely different than $P$ and $NP$. To show you an example for this: Even if $P=NP$ is true, the statement $P^B \neq NP^B$ is still valid. This shows how different $P,NP$ and $P^B, NP^B$ behave.

> It seems to me that we have constructed a language recognizable in NP time but not in P time.

Be careful here. It is shown that unary language $U_B$ can be recognized by a $NP^B$-TM, not by a $NP$-TM. Again, this is because Oracle-Languages/TMs behave completely different than their "normal" counterparts. If you want to recognize $U_B$ in $NP$ without the oracle, you have to do a lot more work as you could guess a word $w$ of length $i$ in poly. time, but you cannot decide $w \in B$ that easy, as we have no clue by BGS if $B \in NP$ or not.

> And if it is not, can it be strengthened into one?

Maybe yes, maybe not. As this would solve $P=NP?$, which is unknown, it is unknown if you could strengthen it or not.

> In the proof there is the sentence "If $P_i^{B(i)}$ accepts $0^n$, then place no string into B at this stage." How can this possibly happen?

As you just simulate all TMs in $P_i^{B(i)}$ and don't change them, you cannot change whether the TM accepts or not. For example, the TM that accepts all words is in $P$, so it also is in $P^B$, so it will be simulated at some point. Then, your case will happen. Of course, this TM will not call the oracle once.

Edit 3:

Now I want to convince you that your Algorithm does not run in $NP$-time. I can't convince you by now that really $B \not \in NP$, but I think I can convince you now at least that this algorithm does not gives us $B \in NP$.

Let's try to formulate your algorithm as an $NP$-TM that decides $w \in B$ (using original BGS, Theorem 3 now):

1. Guess $i$ s.t. $M_i^B(1^{|w|})$ is the poly-TM where $n:=|w|$ is choosen. See that $M_i$ has access to oracle $B$. <s>Guessing $i$ is possible because $i\leq n$ as each stage needs a unique $n$. However, can we verify that $i$ is right? To do so, we might have to really build $B$ from stage $i=0$, which would take to long.</s>

   <s>2. Simulate $M_i(1^{|w|})$ for $2^n/10$ time. I'm not sure whether we can do this. We don't know if $M_i$ is a poly-time TM, so we can't really guess a polynomial $p : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$  so it could really run for $2^n/10$ time as we enumerate all TM's so e.g. also the $EXP$-hard ones. Can you find a fix for this? If so, I will re-edit this answer to describe the next steps.</s> Using original BGS now:
2. Simulate $M_i^B(1^{|w|})$ for $p(|w|)$ time. <s>We can guess the polynomial $p$ in $NP$-time. However, can we verify that $p$ is the right polynomial? We cannot assume that it's right and I can't find an easy way to do this.</s> But here comes the problem: Can we really simulate $M_i^B(1^{|w|})$ in poly. time? I want to convince you that this is not the case.

   2.1. If $M_i^B(1^{|w|})$ writes $x_B$ on the oracle tape and asks $x_B \in B?$, what can we do in $NP$ without the oracle? We can only start another simulation, guess another $i'$ s.t. stage $i'$ takes $n':=|x_B|$ and simulate $M_{i'}^B(1^{|x_B|})$.

   However, how many such new simulations do we have to do in the worst case? $M_i^B(1^{|w|})$ with running time $p(|w|)$ could ask the oracle $p(|w|)$ questions of length $p(|w|)$. Let's look at some arbitrary question at step $j$ now. Let the asked question in step $j$ be $x_B \in B?$. Now, we have to guess $i'$ s.t. $n':=|x_B|$ and simulate $M_{i'}^B(1^{|x_B|})$. Let $p'(|x_B|)$ be the running time of $M_{i'}^B(1^{|x_B|})$. Now, in the worst case, $M_{i'}^B(1^{|x_B|})$ asks the oracle $B$ in every of the $p'(|x_B|) = p'(p(|w|))$ steps again a question of length $p'(|x_B|) = p'(p(|w|))$. And this can go on and on.

   In the end, we have build a tree with the vertex degree being $O(p''(|w|))$ for some polynomial $p''$. The depth of this tree can be pretty huge, because $i$ could equal $i'$. Let's assume just for simplicity that in each step $j$ we asked each stage $k \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$ exactly one question. Then we have depth $n$ for each path from the root to some leaf in the tree. Therefore, to answer the initial question $w \in B?$, we have to look at each of the $O(p''(|w|))^n$ verticies. Clearly, this can only be done in exponentioal time and not in polynomial time, because we have a exponention number of vertecies w.r.t $|w|$. Therefore, the algorithm does not run in $NP$-time.

Comment: “you could guess a word w of length i in poly. time, but you cannot decide w∈B that easy, as we have no clue by BGS if B∈NP or not. ”

We have just constructed the set B. Why cannot we organize it into a two-dimensional table indexed by string length n and 0 <= j < 2^n? Then given n you just guess j.

Comment: I think the problem with your idea is that $B$ is not part of the input. We showed how $B$ is defined, but to check whether $w\in B?$ with  is harder. This basically means that we have to set up all stages of $B$ until stage $j$ where the choosen $n$ is equal to $|w|$. And then we have to simulate $M_i$ for $2^n/10$ steps, which is longer than any polynomial w.r.t. the input size $|w|=n$.
Using a table, I think, cannot be done because $B$ is not part of the input and it cannot be hidden inside the TM-Description because $B$ is an infinite sized language, so the table would be infinitely large

Comment: The set B is infinite but it has a FINITE algorithmic description. Given a string of length n the NP recognizer can simply simulate P_i for p_i(n) steps. If P_i accepts it rejects, if not it accepts.

Comment: I see your point now, thank you! I think the problem with simulating $P_i$ here is that $P_i$ takes $n$ as the unary input, so $1^n$. As a number encoded in binary $n$ bits can have a value of $2^n$, it takes exponentially long to write out the unary string $1^n$ of $n$. You also cannot guess $n$ in unary in $NP$ because this also takes $2^n$ steps. I think this is where this argument of simulating $P_i$ breaks.

Comment: No, 1^n is just a string of length n. It is not a number. In fact in the original BGS paper it is 0^n.

Comment: I updated the answer trying to solve this.

Comment: I am also puzzled vhy nobody has at least considered this argument.

So it seems that at this point we have no choice but to revert to the original BGS proof. There the authors construct a list of polynomial oracle machines P_i. They run in p_i(n) = i + n^i rather than 2^n/10  In these machines we replace the oracle call with a stub that always rejects (initially B is empty), and we simulate these machines as I described.

Comment: So I updated the answer. I totally forgot that in $NP$, you also have to verify what you guessed. However, I cannot find poly. time algorithm to verify that $i$ or the guessed running time polynomial $p$ of $M_i$ is right. Do you have an idea for this?

Comment: Let us say we want to find out if "0000" is in L(B). Suppose that "0101" is in B. So we guess that  "0101" is in B. We need to verify this guess in poly time. We simulate the corresponding P_i. Let us say, for example, that its max running time p_i(4) is 5 questions. It will try 0000, 0001, 0010, 0011, 0100 and stop asking. So it will conclude that 0101 is in B within the hard limit. It is possible that I am misinterpreting something about the BGS proof. I am just asking a question. (No pun intended.)

Comment: I totally forgot that each of the poly-time TMs has access to $B$. Therefore, I think we get an exponential time blow-up in the simulation and the algorithm is not in $NP$. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: WE REPLACE THE ORACLE WITH A STUB THAT ALWAYS REJECTS (initially B is empty). Then my example above applies. It is in NP.

It occurred to me that maybe the counter-argument is something to the effect that the algorithm I am describing does not actually know in which order the strings of length n were generated. But not sure if it refutes it.

Comment: Ok, so if every call to the oracle rejects, then the algorithm should be in $NP$. However, I don't really understand the second part of your comment, sorry. However,

Comment: So if every call to the oracle rejects then the algorithm should be in $NP$. But I don't really understand the second part of your comment, sorry. 
However, I don't think that this algorithm does indeed simulate $M^B_i(1^{|w|})$ the right way. Why should our simulation of this TM be right if we always reject? In the beginning $B$ is empty because it is defined in stages, but when we want to decide some $w \in B$, it could be that many of the answer of some $M^B_i(1^{|w|})$ TM to $B$ are yes. And even one wrong answer could change the output completely, so it's not a correct simulation.

Comment: “when we want to decide some w∈B, it could be that many of the answer of some M^B_i(1^|w|) TM to B are yes” 
This is indeed the critical part. My answer is that we simulate it only for p_i(n) = i + n^i steps. Set B was initially empty so we got “no” for the first p_i(n) steps. The next string of length n  in the canonical enumeration makes it to B. (How else can any string get in B?) So the stub that always returns “no” will be identical with B for p_i(n) steps.